# Readiness and Liveliness Probes is failing for postgresql deployed through helm chart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm trying to deploy postgresql through helm chart by following [postgres-helm](https://bitnami.com/stack/postgresql/helm). The pod is failing to come up and is continuously failing with readiness probes `(Readiness probe failed: 127.0.0.1:5432 - no response)`.Tried increasing the timeout, however no luck. Is there anything which I must have enabled or disabled before hand.

```
Below is my env details - 
 OS : CentOS Linux (7.8.2003)
 K8 : 1.24.0
 Minikube : 1.30.1
```

Attaching the screenshot of pod events and logs
[image]